# Access VBA: If value run two queries, if not run one

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have and insert and update query.

I want to create a button that runs either the insert  query or both the update and insert query.

On the form:

if cbx = values x, y or z, run insert and update.

if cbx does not = values x, y or z run only insert.

So far I have:

```
IF (Cbx=X OR Cbx =Y or cbx =Z) Then

Currentdb.execute("updateQuery")

Currentdb.execute("inserQuery")

ELSEIF (Cbx<>X OR Cbx <>Y or cbx <>Z) THEN

CurrentDB.execute("insertQuery")

ElSE

end if
```

When I run it the table get stuck in what seem like a continuous write/edit loop.

SQL

```
 UPDATE
      tbsurveypersonnel
SET       tbsurveypersonnel.removedDate = DATE()
WHERE
      (
                (
                          (
                                    tbsurveypersonnel.[sr]
                          )
                          =[Forms]![fatbSurveyPersonnelSetRoles]![sr]
                )
                AND
                (
                          (
                                    tbsurveypersonnel.[role]
                          )
                          =[Forms]![fatbSurveyPersonnelSetRoles]![role]
                )
      )
;

INSERT INTO tbsurveypersonnel
      (
                sr
              , lfname
              , role
              , aDate
      )
      VALUES
      (
                (
                          (
                                    tbsurveypersonnel.[sr]
                          )
                          =[Forms]![fatbSurveyPersonnelSetRoles]![sr]
                )
              , ((tbsurveypersonnel.[lfname])=[Forms]![fatbSurveyPersonnelSetRoles]![lfname])
      )
    ,
       (
                (
                          tbsurveypersonnel.[role]
                )
                =[Forms]![fatbSurveyPersonnelSetRoles]![role]
      )
), DATE()
```

final

```
Private Sub AssignRole_Click()

Dim strSql As String
Dim strlSQL2 As String

strSql = "UPDATE tbsurveypersonnel SET tbsurveypersonnel.removedDate = Now() " & vbCrLf & _
     "WHERE removedDate is Null and (((tbsurveypersonnel.[sr])=[Forms]![fatbSurveyPersonnelSetRoles]![sr]) AND ((tbsurveypersonnel.[role])=[Forms]![fatbSurveyPersonnelSetRoles]![role]));"

strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO tbsurveypersonnel ( sr, lfname, role, assigndate ) " & vbCrLf & _
      "SELECT [forms].[fatbSurveyPersonnelSetRoles].[sr] AS Expr1, [forms].[fatbSurveyPersonnelSetRoles].[lfName] AS Expr2, [forms].[fatbSurveyPersonnelSetRoles].[role] AS Expr3, Now() AS Expr4;"

If (Me.role = 1 Or Me.role = 2 Or Me.role = 3) Then

DoCmd.RunSQL strSql

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL2

Else

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL2

End If

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
DoCmd.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: You have the same condition `Cbx<>X OR Cbx <>Y or cbx <>Z` for both if and else if?

Comment: `IF (Cbx="X" OR Cbx ="Y" or cbx = "Z") Then`  the rest can be handled just off the `else`

Comment: Show SQL-Code ([format](https://www.sqlinform.com/online-sql-formatter/) please!) of queries.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher sql with format now in main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid multiple calls to`CurrentDb`as everytime you create a copy (Instance, not Reference!) of the Database (DbEngine(0)(0) usually), what is usually not wanted and can raise errors.

Better store the instance in a variable or expand its scope.

```vb
With CurrentDb
  If (Cbx=X Or Cbx=Y Or Cbx=Z) Then
    .Execute("updateQuery", dbFailOnError)
  End If
  .Execute("insertQuery", dbFailOnError)
End With
```

As`insertQuery`is always executed, it is sufficent to just check if`updateQuery`needs to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Answers the original question:

> if cbx = values x, y or z, run insert and update.

So you want this:

```
IF (Cbx=X OR Cbx=Y OR cbx=Z) Then
    Currentdb.execute("updateQuery")
    Currentdb.execute("inserQuery")
ELSE
    CurrentDB.execute("insertQuery")
end if
```

Comment: I am having and issue when I run this I get a "Too few parameters. Expected 2." Error. The first query, the update query only has two parameters. The queries are being run as objects, not embedded in the vba code.

Comment: Instead of `CurrentDb.Execute` use [`DoCmd.OpenQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openquery) so queries see form values. And there is no need to close action queries.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to ask the same question again.

```
If 'this criteria is met
Then

'Do some code

Else

'Do something else

End If
```

So in practice:

```
IF (Cbx<>X OR Cbx <>Y or cbx <>Z) Then

Currentdb.execute("updateQuery")
Currentdb.execute("inserQuery")

ELSE 

CurrentDB.execute("insertQuery")

END IF
```